# How to assign weights to sample in R

Tags: r

Before performing some statistical analysis I would like to add weights to my sample as a function of a variable (the population size for each areal unit) so that the higher the population size within each unit, the greater the weight it will get and the opposite. Do you have any suggestion on how to do this in R? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SamR's `weighted.mean` requires a weight for each member of your vector.  If you have a population vector with many members and want to weight by a catagories of population size, you could use the base R `cut` function.  Here is a toy example:

```
population <- sample(200:200000, 100)
df <- data.frame(population)
breaks <- c(200, 10000, 50000, 100000, 200000)
labels <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
cuts <- cut(df$population, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
df$weights <- as.numeric(as.character(cuts))
head(df)
  population weights
1      25087     0.2
2      92652     0.3
3      99051     0.3
4     136376     0.4
5     184573     0.4
6     147675     0.4
```

Note that `cuts` is a vector of factors.  Therefore the `as.character(cuts)` conversion is required to maintain the intended fractional weights.

Comment: Hi @SteveM and thanks for your answer. This is actually what I'm trying to do. In my dataset  I have a lot of areal units with small population size and I want to assign different weights so that areal units with higher population size have to be considered more important in the following analysis I'm going to do. Your solution is good, but as it's arbitrary (I mean it's up to me to choose the weights to assign) to your knowledge there is any way to assign weights according to some objective criteria?

Comment: Re: "is any way to assign weights according to some objective criteria?"  The trivial weighting scheme is to just divide the population of each area parcel by the total population.  If you can establish a mathematically proportional relationship between population and some measurable criterion, then pick your population intervals and plug the mid-points of each interval into the relationship equation.  If there are multiple criteria or criteria that can't be measured directly, then you have to implement a process to collect subjective weights, probably from Subject Matter Experts (SME).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`weighted.mean()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/weighted.mean), providing the weights as the second argument.

Here is a quick example, using population as weights.

```r
dat <- data.frame(
    country = c("UK", "US", "France", "Zimbabwe"),
    pop = c(6.7e4, 3.31e8, 6.8e4, 1.5e4),
    love_of_british_royal_family = c(5, 9, 2, 1)
)

mean(dat$love_of_british_royal_family) # 4.25

weighted.mean(
    dat$love_of_british_royal_family, 
    w = dat$pop
) # 8.997391
```

Comment: Hi @SamR, thanks for your answer. What I'm looking for is a bit different. Starting from your example, my aim is to get a weight for each observation (in this case the country) to assign them a different role in the statistical analysis I'm going to perform (that accepted the weight vector  as input). So, in this case, Us and France will get the highest weights while Zimbabwe the lowest.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I am not clear yet. It sounds like you want to take a continuous variable and break it into categories? And then assign each category a weight? Could you edit the question with an example input and the output that you are looking for?